# get pixel color from bitmap android

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to check the color of pixels in a section of a bitmap. I need to determine at what position the black pixels start. Here is my implementation.

```
Bitmap bmp = SavePixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, gl);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++){
        //Log.i(EJ.TAG, i+","+x);
        int pixel = bmp.getPixel(i,x);
        if(pixel == Color.BLACK){
            cordinate = i;
            Log.i(EJ.TAG, i+","+x);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the getPixel method always returns 0

Comment: are you sure about the result of the method SavePixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, gl)? try to save this bitmap on a file and check what's inside

Comment: Is your `Bitmap` correct? Have you tried to convert your ARGB color to HSV using `Color.RGBToHSV()` just for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes I save the bitmap on device to make sure I dont have a blank image. The bitmap iscorrect

Comment: do you need to find the row of the first black pixel, or the column?

Comment: I need to find the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should find the first column (from left) containing a black pixel:

```
    Bitmap bmp = SavePixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, gl);
    boolean found = false;
    for(int x = 0; x < 50 && !found; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 100 && !found; y++){
            int pixel = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
            if(pixel == Color.BLACK){
                cordinate = x;
                found=true;
            }
        }
    }
```